# Spring MVC - Thymeleaf form binding with an arraylist

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

On a specific view I do have an expandable list of employees. Each employee has 2 fields and those are `hoursWorked` & `advancePayments`. With 1 button click, I would like to post the whole form. To achieve this, I'm sending a list to the view that contains several POJOs (based on number of employees).

A POJOs that are added to the list look like this:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class WorkdayCommand {

    private Long employeeId;
    private Integer hoursWorked;
    private Integer advancePayment;
}
```

In a controller, I do have a line to add the list to the model:

```
model.addAttribute("workdayCommands", employeeService.getListOfWorkdayCommandsWithIds());
```

And the method forming the actual list:

```
public List<WorkdayCommand> getListOfWorkdayCommandsWithIds(){

    List<WorkdayCommand> listOfCommands = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Long> listOfIds = employeeRepository.getListOfIds();

    for(int i = 0; i < employeeRepository.getNumberOfEmployees(); i++){

        WorkdayCommand workdayCommand = new WorkdayCommand();
        workdayCommand.setEmployeeId(listOfIds.get(i));
        listOfCommands.add(workdayCommand);
    }

    return listOfCommands;
}
```

Now, I am having a problem with my view:

```
<div class="table-responsive" th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(employees)}">
    <form th:object="${workdayCommands}" th:action="@{/addworkday}">
         some table headers...
         <tr th:each="employee : ${employees}">
              <td><a href="#" role="button" th:href="@{'/employee/' + ${employee.id}}" th:text="${employee.name}">Mike Kowalsky</a></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter hours" th:field="*{hoursWorked}"></td>
              <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter payment" th:field="*{advancePayment}"></td>
              <td><input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/></td>
         </tr>
    </form>
</div>
```

So far, I keep getting an error:

```
NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hoursWorked' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'hoursWorked' is not readable or has an invalid getter method
```

How to properly bind the arraylist with the view? I guess the problem is that there's no such field in the arraylist as `hoursWorked`. What `th:field` parameter should I use, to get to the actual `WorkdayCommand.hoursWorked` field and then iterate through the list to get through all the employees? If you need any more information, feel free to ask any time.

I'm trying with things like:

```
th:field="*{[__${iter.index}__].hoursWorked}"
```

...but that still doesn't work. I can't relate to the first POJO on the list.

**edit 2**

My full view looks like this:
[image]

In a single table row I do have some employee information as well as 2 inputs and 2 buttons. Each row is created thanks to:

```
 <tr th:each="employee : ${employees}">
```

When a submit button is hit, a new Workday object is created and then persisted to the database. When this happens, a Workday needs to be associated to a corresponding employee. So with my:

```
 <tr th:each="employee : ${employees}">
```

...I'm also assigning a hidden `id` field. Then we have the `WorkdayCommand` that gathers all the information from the view. So the `employeeId` field is my way of associating a Workday to a corresponding employee. It should use the `id` value that was passed by for each that displayed all the information. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: You should also iterate on `workdayCommands`, just as on `employees`

Comment: Any leads on where do I do that? In the `form` tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't bind directly to an `ArrayList` aS the `th:object`.  Instead you should create an object that has the ArrayList as a property.

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class WorkdayForm {
    private List<WorkdayCommand> workdayCommands = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Then you loop through, and bind them like this:

```
<form th:object="${workdayForm}" th:action="@{/addworkday}">
  <!-- table headers -->
  <tr th:each="workdayCommand, i : ${workdayForm.workdayCommand}">
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter hours" th:field="*{workdayCommands[__${i.index}__].hoursWorked}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter payment" th:field="*{workdayCommands[__${i.index}__].advancePayment}"></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" th:field="*{workdayCommands[__${i.index}__].employeeId}"/></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- table footers -->
</form>
```

Comment: Alright. That's reasonable. There's 1 more problem tho. First, when iterating through employees, the hidden field `id` gets value assigned. The same value needs to be passed to the `employeeId` field in the backing object. That way, I'll be sure, the hours and payments are assigned to the correct employee. I can't include 2 `th:each` in a single table row... Any clues on how to resolve that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... what is `employeeId` on the `workCommand`?  Why do you need to loop over employees?

Comment: workdayCommand should have an employee as a property of it then... as part of the loop, you could display employee information like this: `<td><a href="#" role="button" th:href="@{'/employee/' + ${employee.id}}" th:text="${workdayCommand.employee.name}">Mike Kowalsky</a></td>`

Comment: Alternatively you could just loop over employee instead of workdayCommand. Everything would stay the same, as far as I can see.