# Thymeleaf th:field inside th:each is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, thymeleaf

I'm trying to render an exam page with my mini-project using this codes

```
public class ExamModel {
    private String question;
    private String answer;
    
    /with setters&getters  
}
```

This Controller return ArrayList of ExamModel

```
@GetMapping(value="/generateexam")
    public String generateExam(Model model){ 
        model.addAttribute("question", examService.generateQuestion());           
        return "exam";
    }
```

This is my html

```
<form th:action="@{/getresult}" th:object="${question}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr th:each="q, i: ${question}">
            <td th:text="${q.question}"></td> 
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{question[__${i.index}__].answer}" value="answer"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Result">
</form>
```

In the browser this is the error message that I'm getting

Caused by:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'question[0]' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'question[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method
```

Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring MVC - Thymeleaf form binding with an arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258295/spring-mvc-thymeleaf-form-binding-with-an-arraylist)